# Updating date field using Hibernate - Row not updated if date is the same, time is different

Tags: oracle, hibernate, updates

I have a situation where a table in the database has a date field defined as date where time also is important (for sorting later).

At first, all times for the date where coming as 000000 but I updated the code to use timestamp and when inserting new records, it's working fine.

Update on the other hand will not change the database if the date is the same (but different time). Apparently, while inserting, hibernate doesn't take into consideration the time and the record is not change (or at least this is what I discovered from my testing).

I can't change the database structure to use timestamp or add a time field.

Any help is really appreciated :)
Thanks